# How to I replace a part of the URL string containing a query using htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

I have a URL string using a PHP query string.
I want to make the URL pretty, but I haven't been able to make the rule properly.

Currently the URL looks like this:

```
http://localhost/pages/map?name=Skyfall-2022
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
http://localhost/pages/Skyfall-2022
```

This is my current htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]


RewriteRule ^pages/(.+)$ /pages/map?name=$1
```

I get a 500 Internal Error with this when I try to type in the desired URL. I don't really understand Regular Expressions so I would appreciate if someone could adjust this for me with an updated .htacces

Comment: I would suggest using the [front controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller) together with a [router](https://packagist.org/?query=router) instead of defining a bunch of URL rules in htaccess. That will allow you to define the URL's in your code directly, which is usually much easier, and will make your code more portable (if you want/need to deploy the site on other web servers that don't read htaccess files)

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely look into it. But I'd still like some help with this just so I have option to use it.

Comment: You issue simply is that you _first_ rewrite _any_ request to its "...php" variant, then its "...html" variant (which does not make any sense) to only then try to rewrite it according to your plan here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following htaccess rules.

Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##External redirect for url change in browser rules here...
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(pages)/map/?\?name=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^  %1/%2? [R=301,L]

##Internal rewrite here for internal file's serving here.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.*)/?$  $1/all-maps.php?name=$2 [QSA,L]
```

***NOTE:*** I have mentioned map? in rewrite rules(2nd set of rules written in comments also in rules), you can change it with your php file's name whatever php file you have to pass query string to.

***NOTE2(OP's fixes as per OP environment):*** tweaked 1 rule a
bit to `$1/all-maps.php?name=$2 to $1/map.php?name=$2` and moved the all-maps.php one directory down and these rules worked fine, mentioned by OP in comments here. Just sharing here, in future it could help people that apart from above rules this was done as part of solution.

Comment: I copied the rules, and cleared the cache. I get a 404 when I try to type in localhost/pages/Skyfall-2022

Comment: @GalenAltaiir, by which php file your internal parameters should be served?

Comment: The URL is passed from a few places, like all-maps.php. I 'echo' it in PHP, so the href looks like this:  'pages/map.php?name=<?php echo $map_title; ?>' and it goes to the desired url which would be the same as in the original post. Not sure if that's what you meant

Comment: @GalenAltaiir, please do check my updated htaccess rules and let me know how it goes.

Comment: so it works, sort of. The problem now is that when I type in http://localhost/pages/map/Skyfall-2022 it takes me to all maps (or http://localhost/pages/all-maps.php). Not sure if's getting confused? Maybe /pages/map/MAP_NAME would work?

Comment: I think I explained that poorly. The final destination is map.php?name=Skyfall-2022. The file all-maps.php just prints the a href to the specific map

Comment: I changed $1/all-maps.php?name=$2 to $1/map.php?name=$2 and moved the all-maps.php one directory down. That seems to work now! Thanks for your help :)